# Is there a way to print all of a certain element of a class that is in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The title is terrible, but hopefully I can explain in my post. Creating a little game as my pet project for python, and I'm currently creating the inventory. Everything was... ok when developing the game until it came to making the function that will show all of the player's inventory.

```
    elif (prompt == "examine"):
        print(inventory[1].name)
        gameprompt()
```

Ok, so I created a list that basically has a bunch of classes from *Items* in it. To call on the name element of these classes I have to do something like this, otherwise I just get its memory location which is largely useless to the player. I've tried

```
    elif (prompt == "examine"):
        print(inventory[].name)
        gameprompt()
```

Thought that this above example would print only the name of all the Item objects, but there's a compilation error instead because I didn't specify which one. So I then tried~

```
        elif (prompt == "examine"):
            print(inventory[1:1000].name)
            gameprompt()
```

Thinking that it would print all of the Item objects names up to 1000, but I obviously don't have that so I thought it would print the names up to the latest object that was there and stop but there was another compilation error from this...

If there is anyway to print out an element of a class for all class objects in a list please let me know. The full code of this game is here, although I don't think you'll need it to help me solve my problem (it is also very large.)

```
playername = input("What is your name?")
zone = 1
movement = 0
restcounter = 0
searchcounter = 0
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, mp, atk, xp, dodgerate, atkrate):
        self.name = playername
        self.hp = hp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atk = atk
        self.xp = xp
        self.dodgerate = dodgerate
        self.atkrate = atkrate

class Enemy(Player):
    def __init__(self, name, gold, maxhp, hp, mp, atk, xp):
        self.name = name
        self.gold = gold
        self.maxhp = maxhp
        self.hp = hp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atk = atk
        self.xp = xp
class Items:
    def __init__(self, name, quantity, description, price, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
        self.weight = weight


Player = Player(playername, 1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 3)
print(Player.name + " has been created. ")



def raceselection():
   raceinput = input("Do you float towards the TEMPLE, CAVE or FOREST?")
    if raceinput == "TEMPLE":
        print("You are now a high elf. High elves utlize a lot of magical power at the cost of being very frail.")
        Player.hp = Player.hp + 24
        Player.mp = Player.mp + 100
        Player.atk = Player.atk + 50
        print("You awaken from your slumber. Your room's walls are gold plated, and you rested on a flat board.")
        print("Out the door, you see many elves with robes praying to some goddess.")
        print("You walk out of your door and into the praying area. You are immediately greeted by a tall man.")
    elif raceinput == "CAVE":
        print("You are now an orc.")
        Player.hp = Player.hp + 1000
        Player.mp = Player.mp + 15
        Player.atk = Player.atk + 50
        print("cave")
    elif raceinput == "FOREST":
        print("You are now a human.")
        Player.hp = Player.hp + 50
        Player.mp = Player.mp + 25
        Player.atk = Player.atk + 25
    else:
        print("You can't float there!")
        raceselection()


raceselection()


inventory = []
def gameprompt():
    global inventory
    global zone
    global movement
    global restcounter
    global searchcounter
    if (movement == 5):
        movement = movement - movement
        zone = zone + 1
        print("You have advanced to zone",zone,"!!!")
        gameprompt()
    if (zone == 1):
        print("Welcome to the first zone! Easy enemies are here with not very good loot./fix grammar, add description of zone/")
    elif (zone == 2):
        print("Hey, it actually travelled to the second zone, awesome!")
    elif (zone == 3):
        print("No way would this actually work!")
    prompt = input("Would you like to walk, search or rest?: ")

    if (prompt == "walk"):
        encounterchance = random.randint(1, 3)
        if (encounterchance == 2):
            if (zone == 1):
                mobspawnrate = random.randint(1,3)
                if (mobspawnrate == 1):
                    Enemy = Enemy("Blue SlimeBall", 50, 0, 25, 15, 25, 0.500)
                    print("You have encountered a " + Enemy.name + "!!!")
                elif (mobspawnrate == 2):
                    Enemy = Enemy("Blue SlimeBall", 50, 0, 25, 15, 25, 0.500)
                    print("You have encountered a " + Enemy.name + "!!!")
                elif (mobspawnrate == 3):
                    Enemy = Enemy("Blue SlimeBall", 50, 0, 25, 15, 25, 0.500)
                    print("You have encountered a " + Enemy.name + "!!!")
        else:
            movement = movement + 1
            print("You have walked a step. You are now at ",movement," steps")
            gameprompt()
    elif (prompt == "search"):
        if (searchcounter == 3):
            print("You cannot search this area anymore! Wait until you reach the next zone!")
            gameprompt()
        else:
            searchchance = random.randint(1, 5)
            if (searchchance == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4):
                searchcounter = searchcounter + 1
                print(searchcounter)
                print("You have found something!")
                searchchance = random.randint(1,4)
                if (searchchance == 1 or 2):
                    inventory.append(Items("Old Boot", 1, "An old smelly boot. It's a mystery as to who it belongs to...", 5, 50))
                    print("You have found a Boot!")
                    print(inventory)
                elif(searchchance == 3):
                    inventory.append(Items("Shiny Boot", 1, "Looks like a boot that was lightly worn. You could still wear this.", 5, 50))
                    print(inventory)
                    print("You have found a Shiny Boot!")
                elif(searchchance == 4):
                    inventory.append(Items("Golden Boot", 1, "It's too heavy to wear, but it looks like it could sell for a fortune!", 5, 50))
                    print("You have found a Golden Boot?")
                    print(inventory)
            else:
                searchcounter = searchcounter + 1
                print(searchcounter)
                print("You did not find anything of value")
           gameprompt()
    elif (prompt == "rest"):
        if (restcounter == 1):
            print("Wait until you reach the next zone to rest again!")
            gameprompt()
        else:
        # Add a MaxHP value to the player later, and the command rest will give 25% of that HP back.
            Player.hp = Player.hp + (Player.hp / 5)
            print("You have restored ",(Player.hp / 5)," hit points!")
            restcounter = restcounter + 1
            gameprompt()
    elif (prompt == "examine"):
        print(inventory[1].name)
        gameprompt()
    gameprompt()
```

Comment: Something like `print([i.name for i in inventory])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension or `map` would work perfectly here:

```
print([item.name for item in inventory])
```

The comprehension iterates the list, and "replaces" each element in  the list with whatever the part before `for` evaluates to. In this case, it's `item.name`.

° It actually doesn't replace the element in the original list. It evaluates to a new list full of replaced items.